# Create indicators while grouping and reshaping

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape, group

I have a data frame `df` of employees, cities (some work in multiple cities) and whether they received the flu shot in a particular year (some years are missing). The range of years is 2005 - 2009. The table looks like this:

```
ID City Year FluShot
1  NY   2006    1  
1  NY   2007    1  
1  BOS  2006    1
1  BOS  2009    0
2  NY   2005    1
3  LA   2006    1
3  NYC  2006    0
3  NYC  2007    1
```

I want to group by `ID` and `City` and have an indicator for every year:

```
ID City Flu05 Flu06 Flu07 Flu08 Flu09
1  NY   0     1     1     0     0
1  BOS  0     1     0     0     1
2  NY   1     0     0     0     1
3  LA   0     1     0     0     0    
3  NY   0     1     1     0     0
```

Can someone help me with this?

I tried `df %>% group_by(ID, City) %>% mutate (Flu05 = (FluShot == 1 & Year == 2005), Flu06 = (FluShot == 1 & Year == 2006), Flu07 = (FluShot == 1 & Year == 2007), Flu08 = (FluShot == 1 & Year == 2008), Flu09 = (FluShot == 1 & Year == 2009))`
and then grouped again by `ID` and `city` to take the sum of these variables. It gives me the correct table but there must be better ways of doing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one potential solution based on the `pivot_wider()` function from the tidyr package (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "ID City Year FluShot
1  NY   2006    1  
1  NY   2007    1  
1  BOS  2006    1
1  BOS  2009    0
2  NY   2005    1
3  LA   2006    1
3  NYC  2006    0
3  NYC  2007    1",
header = TRUE)

df %>%
  mutate(year_short = str_extract(Year, "\\d\\d$")) %>%
  arrange(year_short) %>%
  pivot_wider(-Year,
              names_from = year_short,
              values_from = FluShot,
              names_prefix = "Flu",
              values_fill = 0) %>%
  arrange(ID)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>      ID City  Flu05 Flu06 Flu07 Flu09
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1 NY        0     1     1     0
#> 2     1 BOS       0     1     0     0
#> 3     2 NY        1     0     0     0
#> 4     3 LA        0     1     0     0
#> 5     3 NYC       0     0     1     0
```

### Edit:

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't have a column for "Flu08" (it's not created as the values are all zero). A better solution has been provided in a comment by @Ritchie Sacramento:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "ID City Year FluShot
1  NY   2006    1  
1  NY   2007    1  
1  BOS  2006    1
1  BOS  2009    0
2  NY   2005    1
3  LA   2006    1
3  NYC  2006    0
3  NYC  2007    1",
header = TRUE)

df %>%
  mutate(Year = factor(Year, levels = min(Year):max(Year))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, 
              values_from = FluShot, 
              values_fill = 0, 
              names_glue = "Flu{sub('^20', '', Year)}", 
              names_sort = TRUE, 
              names_expand = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#>      ID City  Flu05 Flu06 Flu07 Flu08 Flu09
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1 NY        0     1     1     0     0
#> 2     1 BOS       0     1     0     0     0
#> 3     2 NY        1     0     0     0     0
#> 4     3 LA        0     1     0     0     0
#> 5     3 NYC       0     0     1     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Try `dat %>%
  mutate(Year = factor(Year, levels = min(Year):max(Year))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = FluShot, values_fill = 0, names_glue = "Flu{sub('^20', '', Year)}", names_sort = TRUE, names_expand = TRUE)` to include any missing years.

Comment: Very interesting approach, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento - your approach is better - would you like to make it an answer and I will delete mine?